# How to unit test nullability of array list in Android?

Tags: android, junit, mockito

I have a method:

```
public void clearLogItems() {
    if (logItems != null) {
        this.logItems.clear();
        this.logItems = null;
    }
}
```

and I would like to write a unit test for it.. If my logic is right, I should check 3 things here:

1. Don't call logItems.clear() if logItems is null
2. Call logItems.clear() if logItems is not null
3. Set logItems to null after calling logItems.clear()

Now I'm not sure how to Mock logItems to null, to verify clear() will be called 0 times..

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class LogItemDataTest {

LogItemData SUT;

@Mock
List<LogItemData> logItems;

@Before
public void setup() throws Exception {
    SUT = new LogItemData();
}

@Test
public void clearLogItems() {
    // Arrange
    // Act
    SUT.clearLogItems();
    // Assert
    Mockito.verify(logItems, times(1)).clear();
}
}
```

With this code, I tried to cover the case where logItems is not null and when logItems.clear() is called 1 time, but when I run it, it says there were 0 interactions with this mock...

How do I mock the logItems list to cover the null case?

Comment: Can you please also post the code of the class LogItemData. With that information I can guide you better about how to fix and improve your test.

Answer (score 0):

The `LogItemData` object `SUT` does not know about the `logItems`. You have to create `SUT` so that it knows about your `logItems`. How that works depends on your implementation of `LogItemData` E.g. if it has a constructor it may look like this

```
@Before
public void setup() throws Exception {
   SUT = new LogItemData(logItems);
}
```